# Как сохранить изображение в указанную папку? (ubuntu, pyautogui)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyautogui

Ubuntu 20.04. Python3. Пользуюсь pyautogui.
Нужно сохранить скриншот области по указанному пути.

```
import pyautogui
import os

img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0, 0, 100, 200))
path = os.path.join('home/name13/Pictures', 'test.jpg')
img.save(path)
```

Ругается: FileNotFoundError
Папка по указанному пути имеется. Ради интереса даже подсовывал файл для перезаписи. Не помогает.
Прошу помощи!

Comment: `home/name13/Pictures` → `/home/name13/Pictures`

Comment: Спасибо! Не углядел!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропущен слеш в начале.

```
/home/name13/Pictures
```

Правильно будет так:

```
path = os.path.join('/home/name13/Pictures', 'test.jpg')
```